# python read file (or string) into dictionary by first separator only

Tags: python, csv

I need to read a file into a dictionary but it contains more than one separator:

```
AGE 32
JOB clerk
NAME Bob Young
```

should become

```
d = {
"AGE": "32",
"JOB": "clerk",
"NAME": "Bob Young"
}
```

`d = pd.read_csv("file.txt", delimiter=" ", header = None).to_dict()[0]` fails since NAME has a second whitespace. How can I suppress the second delimiter?

Comment: Try `str.split`. https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read file by using native python

```
dicti={}
f = open("file.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
for x in f:
    dicti[x.split(' ')[0]]=x.split(' ',maxsplit=1)[1]
 
print(dicti)
```

and output will be:

```
{'AGE': '32', 'JOB': 'clerk', 'NAME': 'Bob Young'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("data_into_dict.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

d = {}
for line in lines:
    if " " in line:
        sep_pos = line.index(" ")
        key = line[0:sep_pos]
        d[key] = line[sep_pos:].strip() # strip() removes \n
print(d)
```

Outputs:

```
{'AGE': '32', 'JOB': 'clerk', 'NAME': 'Bob Young'}
```

Comment: so many good solutions within minutes - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
d = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    for l in lines:
        words = l.split(" ")
        d[words[0]] = ' '.join(words[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution but will change the file so that it is suitable to be read with `read_csv`:

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as f_in, open("data_formatted.csv", "w") as f_out:
    for l in f_in:
        f_out.write(l.replace(" ", ",", 1))
```

`data_formatted.csv` can then be read easily.